# How can I draw a line that moves when the user drags their finger?

Tags: ios, gesture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drawing a line in iPhone / iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783317/drawing-a-line-in-iphone-ipad)

I'd like to draw a line on the screen where the initial point of the line is set when the user first touches the screen, and the second point of the line moves as the user drags their finger. How can I detect these touch and drag events and redraw a line in response to them?

Comment: Read up on the QuartzCore Framework, everything you mentioned can be done with that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783317/drawing-a-line-in-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a drawing application of sorts, check out the `UIBezierPath`. If you wanted to play around with this, take a look at [`MGDrawingSlate`](https://github.com/gtmtg/MGDrawingSlate) (which I created), which is an easy-to-use drop-in UIView subclass that utilizes the `UIBezierPath` for drawing.